# Ownership and lifetime in nested iterators in rust for string comparison

Tags: csv, struct, rust, iterator

I am dipping my toes into Rust and can't seem to figure out how to compare rows of two csv files. I suspect my difficulty arises from trying to tackle the problem in entirely the wrong way, and so I am throwing myself onto the mercies of stackoverflow.

I am writing a simple program that reads two csv files of known fields, and then compares the edit distance of each element of column j in csv1 to each element of column j in csv2 for all columns j in J. At the moment, my code only succeeds in comparing the first row of csv1 to all the rows of csv2.

My pattern is to:

1. read the csvs into a `struct Reader` using the csv and serde crates (all good).
2. Create a `struct Compare` that holds two rows of type Reader, one from each csv.
3. Write a method for Compare that returns the string distances.

I have the core snippets of code below, and the whole thing can be accessed in the rust playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28ab27412f20dcc376e95cf615b5125d).

The `struct Record` will hold a row,

```
#[derive(Debug,Deserialize)]
struct Record {
    mp: String,
    party: String,
    constit: String,
    position: String,
    group: String,
}
```

and the `struct Compare` holds two rows together. I am having it borrow the value because I kept getting a copy error -- but arguably this is where my problems begin!

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Compare<'a> {
    dfa: &'a Record,
    dfb: &'a Record,
}
```

Here I implement a method for Compare that computes the Jaro-Winkler distance for each element of the two rows and returns another struct type defined elsewhere (see the link to rust playground above for the full file):

```
impl <'a> Compare<'a> {
    fn jwdist(&self) -> Stringcomps {
        let res = Stringcomps {
            mp: strsim::jaro_winkler(&self.dfa.mp, &self.dfb.mp),
            party: strsim::jaro_winkler(&self.dfa.party, &self.dfb.party),
            constit: strsim::jaro_winkler(&self.dfa.constit, &self.dfb.constit),
            position: strsim::jaro_winkler(&self.dfa.position, &self.dfb.position),
            group: strsim::jaro_winkler(&self.dfa.group, &self.dfb.group),
        };
        res
    }    
}
```

The following bit of code runs the function (with some toy data). It produces the incorrect output as it only compares the first row of the first csv file to all the rows of the other csv file:

```
fn run() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    // get first df
    let data1 = "mp,party,constit,position,group\n
george,con,bath,whip,no\n
bob,lab,oxford,backbench,yes";
    let data2 = "mp,party,constit,position,group\n
goerge,can,both,wihp,no\n
bob,lob,ofxord,backbenth,yes";
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(data1.as_bytes());
    // get second df
    let mut rdr2 = csv::Reader::from_reader(data2.as_bytes());
    // iterate through both and compare
    for result in rdr.deserialize() {
        let record: Record = result?;
        for result2 in rdr2.deserialize() {
            let record2: Record = result2?;
            let comp = Compare{
                dfa: &record,
                dfb: &record2,
            };
            println!("{:?} compared to {:?}: {:?}", comp.dfa.mp, 
            comp.dfb.mp, comp.jwdist());
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(err) = run() {
        println!("error running example: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

I've tried to fix my problems by initializing the object `comp` before the second for loop but I cannot seem to get it to work. Initialization requires a default method, which I tried to write for Record. I think I got it working but then ran into trouble because the lifetime of the object I was assigning inside the second for loop was too short and would not survive long enough to be printed. This made me pretty convinced that I'm probably tackling the problem wrong.

Apologies in advance: this is a pedagogical project so I am here to get schooled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the code, as is, is not actually very Rust-related, but that you are consuming the readers when you read from them. Your code basically does (in pseudo-code):

```
file1 = open("file1");
file2 = open("file2");
for line1 in read_lines(file1):
    for line2 in read_lines(file2):
        compare(line1, line2)
```

The `file1` is all right, so is the `file2` the first time it is read. But in the second iteration of the outer loop `file2` is at the end-of-file, so no more lines will be read from it and the loop ends.

The easier solution is to read `file2` each time:

```
file1 = open("file1");
for line1 in read_lines(file1):
    file2 = open("file2");
    for line2 in read_lines(file2):
        compare(line1, line2)
```

It is not very efficient because you are reading the same file over and over again.

If you want to read it only once, you can collect all the `Records` from `file2` into a `Vec` and then iterate the `Vec` as many times as needed:

```
let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_reader(data1.as_bytes());
let mut rdr2 = csv::Reader::from_reader(data2.as_bytes());
let lines2 = rdr2.deserialize().collect::<Result<Vec<Record>, _>>()?;

for result in rdr.deserialize() {
    let record: Record = result?;
    for record2 in &lines2 {
        let comp = Compare{
            dfa: &record,
            dfb: record2,
        };
        println!("{:?} compared to {:?}: {:?}", comp.dfa.mp, 
             comp.dfb.mp, comp.jwdist());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an incredibly clear explanation thank you. Could I ask you to explain what this `collect::<Result<Vec<Record>, _>>()?` is doing? is it saying to return a Vec of Record's or else nothing?

Comment: @gfgm: Ah, that is the tricky one! Serde's CSV `deserialize()` returns an iterable of `Result<Record, _>` with the parse result of each line. But I'd like to get a `Result<impl Iterable<Record>, _>` to apply the `?` easily to the whole file. How to do it? It happens that `Result<V, E>` implements `FromIterator<Result<A,E>>` (if `V` implements `FromIterator<A>`), that means that I can `collect()` the iterator of results into a result of a vector! Then just apply the `?` operator and you have a `Vec<Record>`. The only drawback is that you have to specify the type to `collect()`.

Comment: The end result is that if any line of the file yields a parse error, the whole file is considered an error and the `?` ends the function with an `Err`.